# No vertical centering in table in cell first row, first column

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I am struggling with the following problem. Let's assume I have this sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{P{2cm} | P{4cm} | P{4cm} | P{2cm}}
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3\end{tabular}}
        &
        {\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3\end{tabular}}
        &
        {\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3\end{tabular}}
        &
        \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Line 1\\Line 2\end{tabular}}
        \\
         & \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit} & \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit} & \\
        \toprule
        A & Lorem ipsum dolor sit & Lorem ipsum dolor sit & B \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The following output get's produced:

[image: table]

My problem: In the first row, first column I would like to have also the three lines vertically centered. How to achieve this?!

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean first row or (as you use multirow) the first two rows?

Comment: I mean the cell in the first row, first column "as you see it". So I would like to have
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
vertically centered on the whole, as it is for example with
Line 1
Line 2
in the cell in the first row, last column.

Sorry, maybe I should have chosen different names, so that it's easier to understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\makecell` and don't use vertical lines with `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\leavevmode\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{P{2cm}  P{4cm}  P{4cm}  P{2cm}}
            \toprule
            \makecell{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3}
            &
            \makecell{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3\\ \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}}
            &
            \makecell{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3\\ \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}}
            &
            \makecell{Line 1\\Line 2}
            \\      
            \toprule
            A & Lorem ipsum dolor sit & Lorem ipsum dolor sit & B \\
            \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is this what you intend?

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks nice! Such a fast answer and also a solution, which makes the code a lot more readable ;)

Comment: @Joojoo You're welcome! We are always happy to help users who provide a complete minimal working example!